# Facebook Posting with Python Automation

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to automate posting to facebook in 2 ways, cannot find any answers online. Everything seems to be outdated. Anybody here have any experience with it?

1. Way  through Facebook library:

```
import facebook

def post_to_facebook():
    # Replace 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' with your actual access token
    access_token = 'Acces Token'
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=access_token, version='3.0')


    try:
        # Upload photo or video
        graph.put_object("me", "feed", message="test post", link="https://www.gainsberg.co.uk/")
        print("Post successful!")
    except facebook.GraphAPIError as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

post_to_facebook()
```

Where it drops error:

```
Error: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \
          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \
          sufficient administrative permission
```

2. Way through Request:

```
import requests

# Your Access Keys
page_id = "61556299207020"
facebook_access_token = 'Token'
msg = 'Some message here'

post_url = f'https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed'
response = requests.post(post_url, params={'access_token': facebook_access_token, 'message': msg})

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Post successfully created!")
else:
    print(f"Error creating post. Status code: {response.status_code}")
    print(response.json())  # Print the error details
```

Where it drop error:

```
Error creating post. Status code: 400
{'error': {'message': '(#100) The global id 61556299207020 is not allowed for this call', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 100, 'fbtrace_id': 'A8-v8UlMZkuEpZ6iamY0ZDn'}}
```

I was trying to automate posting to Facebook, so after running this programs it would post to profile.

Comment: are you trying to post to a page that you are an admin at?

Comment: Yeah it is my page

Comment: You should really not expose real access tokens here. But since you already did - your `facebook_access_token` is a _user_ access token, according to the token debug tool.

Comment: i have this error when using a write token when assigned all avaiable permissions. 
(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \
          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \
          sufficient administrative permission